# data not showing up in html component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

here i'm accessing a video detail so i have this typescript file :

```
    export class CandidatComponent implements OnInit {
  video$: Observable<VideoPayload>  = new Observable<VideoPayload>();; 
 // video: Observable<VideoPayload> = new Observable<VideoPayload>();
  permaLink: Number = 0;

  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private videoService: VideoService,private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.permaLink = params['id'];
    });

    this.video$ = this.videoService.getVideo(this.permaLink); // assign the observable

    //this.video$ = this.videoService.getVideo(this.permaLink);
     this.video$.subscribe((data:VideoPayload) => {
   
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
      console.log(data);
    },(err: any) => {
      console.log('Failure Response');
    })
  }

}
```

in the console.log i get the data i need but in the html it's just empty.
in html i just use

```
<div  *ngIf="(video$ | async) as video">
  <h3 >
    {{video.title}} 
  </h3>
  <p>{{video.description}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are subscribing twice, manually, and reactively. Since you are not doing anything in particular when you subscribe manually, remove the `subscribe` and let the `async` pipe handle the rest.

Additionally, you are handling the `route` params and the `getVideo` wrong. You are, again, subscribing manually to route params, and **outside** of the `subscribe`, you are getting the video, and you are expecting to have `permaLink` with data... which is wrong because `permaLink` will be filled with data inside the `subscribe` instance because of `asynchronous` code.

The correct and reactive way could be like the following:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.video$ = this.router.params.pipe(
   tap(params => this.permaLink = params['id']),
   switchMap(params => {
     const permaLink = params['id'];
     return this.videoService.getVideo(permaLink);
   })
 );
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="(video$ | async) as video">
  <h3 >{{ video?.title }} </h3>
  <p> {{ video?.description }}</p>
</div>
```

Also, why do you require to trigger (by force) change detection with `ChangeDetectorRef`? You don't need it, I suggest you remove that dependency from your component.

**UPDATE**

Given your comment, you have an `array` of data, notice the square brackets, that is an array:

```
[ { "id": 5, "title": "TITLEU35WITHREQUEST", "description": ... ]
```

You either make use of `*ngFor` for looping through all the data elements individually or, in this case, just grab the first element since I think is just one:

```html
<!-- With ngFor for multiple data items -->
<ng-container *ngIf="(video$ | async) as videos">
  <div *ngFor="let video of videos">
    <h3 >{{ video?.title }} </h3>
    <p> {{ video?.description }}</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>

<!-- or grab the first element -->
<!-- you could also pipe the observable and map it so you don't have to -->
<!-- manually grab the first element like this: [0] -->
<ng-container *ngIf="(video$ | async) as video">
  <h3 >{{ video[0]?.title }} </h3>
  <p> {{ video[0]?.description }}</p>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: i tried that but i still have the issue and i don't understand why i don't get the data in the html

Comment: in the console i get this data :
`
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "TITLEU35WITHREQUEST",
        "description": "DESCREPTIONEUU45",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/aR0pyhjeFRE",
        "user": {
            "id": 12,
            "firstName": "ddsam",
            "lastName": "cccak,k",
            "authorities": [
                {
                    "authority": "ROLE_CANDIDAT"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
`
but nothing in the html

Comment: you're right, also i had to add the array type whenever i call the model (payload) like so:
video$: Observable<VideoPayload[]>  = new Observable<VideoPayload[]>();

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the $ syntax, but your html should probably look more like this:

```
<div  *ngIf="video">
  <h3 >
    {{video.title}} 
  </h3>
  <p>{{video.description}}</p>
</div>
```

and your ts file should probably look like this

```
subscribe((data:VideoPayload) => {
  this.video = data;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work at all ://

Comment: are you getting data from your api?

Comment: yes i am but not in the html somehow

Comment: if you are getting data, then the above code would be working. add a console.log statement to see what the data looks like.